# Date column value changes because of DST

Tags: web-services, column, date-time

A list includes a column "Date" of type `Date and Time`, Date and Time Format is `Date Only`. An item is saved via web-service and is set to value such as `2013-04-01T00:00:00Z`.

When this same item is saved via website (nothing needs to be changed), the column continues to read on website as "1/13/2013" but web-service now returns `2013-03-31T23:00:00Z`.

In other words, we write to SharePoint `2013-04-01T00:00:00Z`, do nothing with this value and then we get back `2013-03-31T23:00:00Z` instead of original value.

This may be related to the fact that DST kicked in on Sunday, March 31.

Is there a way to prevent SharePoint form changing the date without resorting to storing date as string and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way (that I know of) to prevent SharePoint from converting dates between local and UTC times.

When you save the date via web service with the value of `2013-04-01T00:00:00Z` it is saved directly as you specified (which is UTC). When you save that value via the website (I assume as a field in a list) then SharePoint will translate that value to UTC based on the time zone settings of the Web. (aka Site). In your case this appears to be UTC+1. Note that when you enter the time into a Date column, you are NOT specifying `2013-04-01T00:00:00Z`, you are providing a simple date string, (for example, 4/2/2013 in the US) which is transated to UTC.

If data is both saved and retrieved from the list programmatically, then you can handle the difference however you'd like. However, if you are using the SharePoint user interface to either enter or retrieve the data then you should adjust your handling of the date in your programming to account for the change.

Here is a useful web page:
http://www.stum.de/2010/06/10/dealing-with-multiple-time-zones-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: That looks like a good explanation. Web site's timezone however is "(UTC) GMT", would you expect this scenario to hold?

Comment: Yes, due to daylight savings as you mentioned. I confirmed the same behavior on a site of mine. To completely avoid this, I imagine you would need to select "(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time". Note that changing the time zone of a site will not update any data, so after changing the time zone you could see incorrect dates.

Comment: Yes, that's what we're observing as well. Changing to "UTC Universal Coordinated Time" fixes the problem, as well as changing field's format from `Date Only` to `Date and Time`.